# Xamarin: Android application crashes after starting another application

Tags: android, crash, xamarin

I am building a Xamarin Android Application. The problem is that when the I pause the application, start another application and then reselect it, the application  crashes very often and starts again from the first activity. I think that this part of the log shows the problem and I don't have the faintest idea how I could fix it:

> 01-15 16:10:46.211: W/MonoDroid-Debugger(3372): Not starting the
>   debugger as the timeout value has been reached; current-time:
>   1421334646  timeout: 1421334471 01-15 16:10:46.401: W/libc(3372):
>   WARNING: generic atexit() called from legacy shared library 01-15
>   16:10:46.421: D/Mono(3372): Image addref mscorlib[0x7187cdb8] ->
>   mscorlib.dll[0x7187c1d8]: 1 01-15 16:10:46.421: D/Mono(3372): AOT
>   module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/data/CSMobile.UI/lib/mscorlib.dll.so" not found

Moreover when I am running dumpsys meminfo command to see the memory allocation after using the application for a while the number of the view objects rises dramaticaly and the heap size as well. The view objects reach 3000 and maybe more.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886168/android-app-startup-problems-growing-heap) maybe the problem is a high resolusion image.But even if I delete the only high resolution image (600 x 1000) that I have, the application continues crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the RAM usage of the device was in a critical level. I've tested my application in other devices with RAM usage in normal levels without having this issue.

Comment: how can we solve this problem with low ram devices? Apps like fb,whatsapp working fine in those devices.